# JSONDecodeError at / Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, django

i am having such error which i cant debug

```
from .services import GetList,GetAPIkey,GetAPIurl

class ApiListView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        list_view = GetList().get_list_data()
        movie_list = list_view.json()
        if self.request.session.has_key('email'):
            email = self.request.session['email']
            context = {
                'movie_list':movie_list,
                'email':email
            }
        else:
            context = {'movie_list': movie_list}
        return render(request, 'home-index.html', context)
```

traceback error shows error is showing error is here `movie_list = list_view.json()`

```
import requests


class GetList():
    def get_list_data(self):
        API_KEY = '***********8'
        API_URL = 'http://devstudio.cnedocent.com/rest/getContentList'
        parameters = {'authToken': API_KEY,'permalink': 'movie'}
        r = requests.get(url=API_URL, params=parameters)
        return r
```

Comment: What is `GetList` here?

Comment: @JPG it a class where i have called apis

Comment: Add `GetList` class too

Comment: @JPG HAVE UPDATED

Comment: you should print your response to make sure it's actually giving you back a json document. e.g. `print(list_view.raw)` or `print(list_view.content)`

Comment: The **`.json()`** method returns a ***json-encoded content of a response, if any***.Your response is **not** a JSON at this point. That's might be the issue

Comment: Print the list view before the error

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak Are you sure you are getting 200 response? you can test it with `r.status_code`